# pyautogui не выводит английские и русские буквы

Tags: python, текст, pyautogui

Пишу какой нибудь примитивный код с помощью модуля pyautogui, все команды работают кроме вывода текста.

Например:

```
import time
import pyautogui

time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(213, 48)
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello123!$%fkd')
```

Из всего этого выводится "123!", вне зависимости какая стоит у меня раскладка, русская или английская, выводятся только цифры и некоторые символы.
Пытался найти решение, но не нашёл.
Как можно это исправить чтоб всё адекватно выводилось?

Comment: А куда выводится? Может в том поле ввода, куда вы это печатаете, ввод ограничен определёнными символами. Ну, если я правильно понимаю, о чём речь вообще.

Comment: Например выводится текст в строку браузера, я отредактировал своё сообщение, и написал уже полноценный пример кода для этого, из кода в строку браузера выводится только 123!%

Comment: А это читали, пробовали советы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582155/missing-symbols-in-pyautogui-typewriter

Comment: И вот это ещё https://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread1833042.html

Comment: Cпасибо, только что копался в системных настройках, поменял приоритет языка на английский, и всё заработало!

Comment: Если вам не лениво, можете оформить как ответ на свой вопрос, только добавьте в него ссылку на источник информации.